# How to fix APEX login redirect in cypress?

Tags: oracle-apex, cypress

When I instruct cypress to login to an Oracle APEX application, the authentication re-directs cypress to a '404 not found' page because the authenticated URL is somehow malformed. The malformed URL is the only issue and can simply corrected programmatically (with a find and replace command):
[image: 404]

However - it is very important to note that the cypress login correctly returns:
1. a valid cookie
2. a valid session
, which is everything you need for authentication.

I have tested this across 4 instances of Oracle APEX (APEX 5.0, 5.1, 18.1 and 19) and this behavior is consistent.

I created a dummy application with dummy credentials hosted by apex.oracle.com to demonstrate:

```
it('Login demo', function() {
    cy.visit('https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54707:LOGIN_DESKTOP')
    cy.get('#P9999_USERNAME').type('ApexUser')
    cy.get('#P9999_PASSWORD').type('Oradoc_db1')
    cy.get('.t-Button').click()
  })
```

The above code (which should work until the application expires in many months) will redirect to a 404 not found page with a url in the format:

https://apex.oracle.com/__/f?p=54707:1:[session_id]:::::

Outside of cypress the url will have the format:

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54707:1:[session_id]::::: (this is the desired result)

Comment: Interesting addition: The above issue is unique to the chrome browser in cypress. Turns out using the Electron browser in cypress doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Incorrect. Issue manifests in Electron too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved in the Chrome 77 browser.